# Can I trust user information supplied to a functions.https.onCall function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am considering writing an app using firebase. As part of my app I need to execute code in a trusted environment (to prevent user tampering), hence a firebase function.

[The firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) specifies an https onCall function, which provides some user data, such as the username and password as well as the uid. Is this data trustworthy or could an unscrupulous user forge credentials?

Comment: The link above is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. In the [protocol specification for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#request_format_headers) firebase state that they verify the user credentials (most importantly, the user's auth token). Any requests supplied without valid user credentials are rejected.